# Parent-child event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have have a 2 div element. One is child and one is parent like :

```
<div id="p">
  <div id="c">
  </div>
</div>
```

The `parent` div has 2 event attached `click` and `dblclick` and child div has 1 event attached `click`. Now my problem is when i clicked on the `child div` the parent div click event also executed. I tried `e.stopPropagation();` but still same behavior. Help me ?

Comment: could you post your javascript? Maybe it's a small typo :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have tried it wrong, because [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) should do the trick here. Make sure you stop the propagation of the event at the child element:

```
$("#c").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //Will prevent event bubbling to #p
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8GuzJ/).

---

The only exception to the above is if you have bound the event handlers with the `live` method (which you shouldn't be doing since `live` is deprecated). You cannot stop the propagation of `live` events since the event handler is bound to the document, rather than the element, and the event has to propagate all the way to the document before it is executed.

Comment: If you are stuck using an older version of jQuery `.delegate()` will work and stopPropagation works with it as well. Just a tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Beside using `stopPropagation` you can also check for a condition before handling the event (an [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/) approach). This way you can also use `live` event handlers (replaced by `on` in jQuery nowadays, if I'm correct). See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/hkKLq/)

[**edit**]: using `bind`, you'll only need one handler for all, defined for `div#p`. The provided jsfiddle is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: `live` is deprecated... and also `delegate` should be used over live for older versions (and bind in the oldest of old)... `stopPropagation` does not work in `live` - also `live` is slow and cannot be chained. http://api.jquery.com/live/ see here

Comment: I didn't say he *had* to use `live`, I merely pointed to it as a possibility. Event delegation, furthermore, doesn't have to be at document level per se. It's perfectly usable at the level of some root element, and handy for, say, xhr refreshed sub-elements of such an element. In case of the jsfiddle I provided, it's merely a click handler on a root element.